# Calender.SelectedDate - DateTime.Now;

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, calendar

```
lblService = CalService.SelectedDate - DateTime.Now;
```

I'm trying to work out how many days until the selected date.
This crashes the program.
I have also tried

```
DateTime daysTillService = CalService.SelectedDate - DateTime.Now;
```

This causes this error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan?' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: When you substract dates you get a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: DateTime.Today works?

Comment: When you perform arithmetic operation on two dates the result is time span, not another datetime. That's why you are getting this error. Also you never get another date when you subtract one date from another. You need to subtract days, months, or years to get another date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int daysTillService = (CalService.SelectedDate.HasValue) ? (int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(CalService.SelectedDate.Value).TotalDays : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you subtract two DateTime values you actually return a **TimeSpan** which is why you are experiencing an exception.

```
TimeSpan lblService=CalService.SelectedDate.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

Then store the number of days between the two DateTime values as an int:

```
int DaysBetween=(int)lblService.TotalDays;
```